# How to convince my parents to let me study biotechnology instead of MBBS?

Tags: family, conflicts, parents, india, students

From my childhood, I haven't had any dream of becoming something but my parents always wanted me to study and become a doctor and that's why they enrolled me in Neet Coaching (*The National Eligibility cum Entrance Test (Undergraduate), formerly the All India Pre-Medical Test, is an entrance examination in India for students who wish to study undergraduate medical courses and dental courses in government or private medical and dental colleges in India, Source: Wikipedia*) when I was in 8th grade.

I didn't know anything at that time, I thought it was some tuition which will help me for studying. But by 10th grade, I understood that my parents were serious about me becoming a doctor.

I did my research about it and I didn't like it. I mean I didn't feel like I would be a great student in that, though I didn't have an alternative course I liked.

I tried telling my parents that I don't think MBBS (*Bachelor of Medicine and Bachelor of Surgery*) is the right course for me, but they were so mad and disappointed in me when I said that. I thought I needed a good reason not to be a doctor.

I continued my Neet coaching until 12th grade. I am not an A-grade student just an average grade.

Now I have somehow passed my boards and I have found a course I like that is B.TECH Biotechnology.

I told my parents but they are thinking that I have been cheating on them and I have betrayed them all this time. I didn't tell them because I knew something like this would happen and I didn't want to disappoint them, but it would hurt them even more if I were to drop out in the middle of MBBS, plus I like biotechnology and I think I would be a good student in this field.

How can I convince them I should choose the program I study?

Comment: This really should have a culture tag.  The advice you'd get for Indian or Asian parents could be very different than for English (non-Indian) parents

Comment: This question is an exact copy from: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/154357/how-to-convince-my-parents-to-accept-me-to-study-biotechnology-instead-of-mbbs#comment411345_154357

Comment: Can you break down your question into single sentences that end with a full stop/dot and introduce line breaks?

Comment: Hi I dont know! Could include in your question a.) The arguments you used to try to convince your parents and b.) how you presented those arguments. Like our [help/on-topic] says, we can help you mediate conflict but coming up with arguments you can use to convince your parents is out of scope of this site. And including how you've already presented those arguments (if any) will help prevent answers stating things you've already tried. Also, the location/culture tag is probably very important here, and could you clarify what Neet and MBBS are?